# Overheating pt cruiser

Tags: pt-cruiser

I have a 2004 PT cruiser 2.4 liter turbo engine & it started overheating on me yesterday. Today I replaced the thermostat & the radiator cap. I also bled the system of all air. Why is it still overheating?

Comment: Are the radiator fans working?

Comment: Obviously there is a problem beyond the parts you replaced.  How about the water pump?  Perhaps the radiator is clogged.  Possibly one of your coolant lines is plugged.  Keep checking stuff until you find the cause of the overheating.